# Handle POSTing a file to a server (and giving it a unique URL) in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, post, server

I am using the following code to upload a file to a node.js server:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/upload" method="post">
    <input id="image-file" type="file" />
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

How do I handle this on the server's end? I want to make the file accessible at a URL I am generating with `uuid`:

```
var timeBasedID = uuid.v1();
    console.log(timeBasedID);  
var url = 'https://mgphn-files.glitch.me/' + timeBasedID;
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: here is basically what my server looks like:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
var uuid = require('uuid');
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.get("/", function(request, response) {
  response.sendFile(__dirname + "/views/index.html");
});

app.post("/upload", function(request, response) {
  //code to handle upload would go here
});   

// listen for requests :)
const listener = app.listen(process.env.PORT, function() {
  console.log("Your app is listening on port " + listener.address().port);
});
```

Comment: What does your server look like? Are you using a framework of some kind? It’s kind of open ended without some additional details and probably too broad.

Comment: You should use npm package multer to handle file upload. With multer u will get access to uploaded file in req.files